# cat-ing non-empty file to itself makes it empty. Why?

Tags: linux, command-line, redirection

Can you please explain me why:

```
cat < file.txt > file.txt
```

makes `file.txt` empty?

This is observed in Bash in Linux.

Comment: Just to add to the bottom two answers: if you wanted to make a loop (endlessly filling `file`) you could type `cat <file.txt >>file.txt` as two >> mean appending to instead of deleting the file.

Comment: Yikes.  That's just scary.  I've never even thought of using (abusing?) cat and pipes like that!  That's why we have the "touch" command.  ;-)  Makes for a cool example though.

Answer (score 16):

Because it opens and truncates the file before reading the data — it being shell, the redirections are processed by shell before even starting `cat`.

Answer (score 13):

The `>` redirection happens first and opens `file.txt` for writing which clears any existing content.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading -- @hacker's is more precise.  On my systems, the redirections are processed in order of specification.  That is, `<` happens first, and then `>`, but the latter opens not merely "for writing" but *with truncation* (`O_TRUNC`), which is what "clears existing content."  @hacker is right, this happens before `cat(1)` is even executed.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of `Bash`, where we assume the filename is `file.txt`. Note that different shells may have different implementations.

> Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.

So it's not because of which "happens first".

The pseudo-code to accomplish `STDIN_FILENO = 0` is as follows

```
fd = openat(AT_FDCWD, "file.txt", O_RDONLY);
dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

The pseudo-code to accomplish `STDIN_FILENO = 1` is as follows

```
fd = openat(AT_FDCWD, "file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

These occur sequentially before the `cat` is executed.

For the following two ways:

- ```
  cat < file > file
  ```
- ```
  cat > file < file
  ```

The difference is only in **the order** in which the pseudocode executes both.

> **O_TRUNC**
> If the file already exists and is a regular file and the access mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to length 0.

Not surprisingly, if you specify output redirection, the contents of `file.txt` will be cleared during the opening of the file.

Comment: (1) Welcome to Super User. The question is old, answered long ago, but your answer contains technical details not present in the old answers. Nice debut. (2) "different shells may have different implementations" – It's worth noting that for many shells these possibly "different implementations" lead to the same result. The behavior is standard, mandated by POSIX, very common. Even `zsh` (that deviates from POSIX standard where it finds the standard goofy or harmfully surprising) does redirections this way.